# Solve for $x: 2/\sqrt{2-x^2} = 4- 2x^2?$

Tags: calculus

How do you expand and solve for $x$?

It is $2 = 4\sqrt{2-x^2} - 2x^2\sqrt{2-x^2}$

Thank you!

How would I solve for x?

Comment: Jesse, when you find an answer to be particularly helpful, you can accept it (we encourage you to do this). You can accept *one* answer per question you ask. To accept an answer, click on the $\large \checkmark $ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept: it turns green, and you get two reputation points just for accepting an answer!

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{\sqrt{2-x^2}} &= 4 - 2x^2\\
2 &= 2(2-x^2)^{3/2}\\
1 &= (2-x^2)^{3/2}\\
1 &= 2-x^2\\
1 &= x^2\\
\pm1 &= x
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Note that real solutions of $x$ occur for $|x|\lt\sqrt 2$.  Then start by dividing by $2$:

$$1=(2-x^2)\sqrt{2-x^2}=(2-x^2)^{3/2}$$

$$\implies 1=2-x^2 \implies x^2=1$$

Which implies that $x=\pm 1$.

Comment: Also you should be careful solving an equation or an inequality where they are defined. In this case the equation is defined for $-\sqrt{2}<x<\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $4-2x^2 = 2(2-x^2)$.

Muliplying both sides by $\sqrt{2-x^2}$ shows that any solution of the equation also solves $2 = 2 (2-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$, or equivalently $(2-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}} = 1$.

This is equivalent to solving $2-x^2 =1$, which yields $x^2 = 1$, from which we get $x = \pm 1$.